# Что произойдёт при выполнении запроса к материализованному представлению, во время его обновления?

Tags: oracle

Есть мат.представление

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW emp2 
REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT 
AS SELECT * FROM emp;
```

Допустим кто-то внёс изменения в таблицу emp, зафиксировал (commit). Представление начинает обновляться, и тут кто-то другой выполняет запрос к emp2. Что произойдёт?

Как сделать так, чтобы вернулись обновленные данные? Как это сделать за счет ожидания изменившего и как это сделать засчет ожидания запросившего?

Comment: *"Что произойдёт?"* - а взять и проверить - никак?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov, проверить можно. Но это только часть вопроса. И практический результат одно, а теоретическое обоснование (т.е. ответ на "а почему так?") другое. И еще, вы предлагаете каждому кто столкнулся с этим вопросом проверять это самому?

Comment: Конечно. Это - самый надежный способ...

Comment: @PavelMayorov здесь высокий риск нарваться на редко проявляющийся феномен (e.g. обновление занимает 10 мс, а в синтетических тестах запрос на чтение приходит через 15 мс), поэтому я бы крайне не рекомендовал проводить неподготовленные исследования в подобной области.

Comment: @Etki ясен пень что надо обновление растянуть. Например, сделать UPDATE SET Foo=1 на таблице в миллион записей.

Comment: @PavelMayorov мертвому припарки. Движок БД представляет собой черную коробку, которая имеет право докинуть запись в таблицу любой длины за произвольное время, да и вообще пример со временем - это лишь один из способов прострелить себе колено на таких тестах, все их предвидеть очень сложно.

Answer (score 2):

Refresh по сути не должен блокировать доступ к индексированному представлению (материализованному), т.е. по сути создаются новые физические записи на диске, а не перезаписываются.

А вот если делается ALTER VIEW, то происходит его монопольная блокировка